# istanbul code coverage with mocha tests with coffeescript

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, code-coverage, mocha.js, istanbul

I'm using mocha to run tests that are purely in coffeescript. I also want to be able to use istanbul to generate code coverage reports.

Note, I'm using mocha with option `--compilers coffee:coffee-script/register` within the `mocha.opts` file.

The issue I'm running into is that tests that require other coffeescript source files aren't covered. If instead, I require js files, it's covered fine.

Am I missing something?

---

My `npm test` command is: `istanbul test --report html -x 'vendor/**' _mocha`. I use `npm test --coverage` to enforce istanbul's coverage utility.

Here is a sample of a mocha test (./test/test.coffee):

```
# Project
# require ../src/main.coffee
main = require('../src/main')

# Chai
chai = require('chai')

assert = chai.assert
should = chai.should()
expect = chai.expect


describe 'something', (done) ->

  describe "when given something", ->

    it "should do this", ->
        # tests using chai API here
        something = new main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [coffee-coverage](https://github.com/benbria/coffee-coverage) instead with [these instructions](https://github.com/benbria/coffee-coverage/issues/36).

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching around for this as well. It doesn't look like istanbul can cover CoffeeScript files (although there is [a pull request open](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/pull/167), so hopefully we'll see it soon). There's a project called [ibrik](https://github.com/Constellation/ibrik) which uses istanbul and a CoffeeScript parser to cover your code. However, I can't seem to find how to integrate it with Mocha yet. [A problem which a lot of people seem to have](https://github.com/Constellation/ibrik/issues/11).

Comment: coffee-coverage FINALLY has support for Istanbul, and is super easy to get going with mocha: https://github.com/benbria/coffee-coverage/blob/master/docs/HOWTO-istanbul.md